# How do I get the resource id when dropping external event onto resourceWeek?

Tags: jquery, html, fullcalendar

Building a crew scheduler calendar using FullCalendar.  Everything is going good until I drop a job from the left onto a day and crew. I need to get the resource row that was selected at time of drop.

[image: JobSchedule]

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'Resource Scheduling',
            right: 'resourceWeek,resourceMonth'
        },
        editable: true,
        droppable: true,        
        defaultView: 'resourceWeek',    
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,         
        drop: function(date, allDay, ev, ui) {

// retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

// assign it the date that was reported
copiedEventObject.start = date;
copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

//Get Resource (**HELP**)
copiedEventObject.resource = 'resource1'; //hard coded works
copiedEventObject.resource = $(this).data <resource>; //Where is it?
```

Comment: It always helps to add a bit of code and markup to your question. but did you try something like  `copiedEventObject.resource = $(this).attr('resource');`  ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried...

```
drop: function (date, allDay, ev, ui, res) {

// retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

// assign it the date that was reported
copiedEventObject.start = date;
copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

//Get Resource (**HELP**)
//copiedEventObject.resource = 'resource1'; //hard coded works
//copiedEventObject.resource = $(this).data <resource>; //Where is it?
copiedEventObject.resourceId = res.id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this link for get Resource ID:
https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1594
I have resolved this one but note for this you need to change into default fullcalandar.js file.
In function this. I have commented the default line and added this one into fullcalendar.js

```
function dragStop(_dragElement, ev, ui) {
    var cell = hoverListener.stop();
    clearOverlays();
    if (cell) {
        trigger('drop', _dragElement, cellDate(cell), cellIsAllDay(cell), resources[cell.col].id, ev, ui);
        //trigger('drop', _dragElement, cellDate(cell), cellIsAllDay(cell), ev, ui);
    }
}
```

Comment: Link only/mainly answers are frowned upon here - if you can put the important aspects into your answer that would be better.